# One JS in several JSPs

Tags: javascript, jsp

So I am a novice in JS.

I have one JS file and around 25 JSPs
What I want to do is that I want to include this one JS into around 19 of these JSPs.

I understand that it can be done manually one by one by using tag. But is it possible to attain this in a more efficient way?

Comment: And all these JSP files are completely independent? They don't include a common header or something of that sort? If not, you can always write a `ServletFilter` to inject the JavaScript.

Comment: Can you be more precise about more efficient way? If you don't want to use a tag then you can inject a JavaScript code using JSP variable but it leads to XSS.

Comment: There's no generic answer, but it's also a trivial amount of editing. If you don't want to restructure your JSPs *(or general view architecture)* so they can easily share behavior just edit 19 files or get a list of those files and inject it into the source from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way is using

```
<script src="/if_js_file.js"></script>
```

or

```
<jsp:include page="/if_jsp_file.jsp"/>
```

tags.

Use this on your jsp and use that jsp as a template.

Other ways requires you to develop a servlet, that is going to be faster when finished, but in first instance you're gonna spend more time than just using tags.